# ImageMagick, set relative size in chain of convert operators

Tags: imagemagick

I'd need to set the size relative to the size already set. I'd need it because my flow involves defining primitives inside other ones. Eg

```
convert -size 200x100 xc:black \( -size 30x40% xc:red \) -gravity West -composite out.png
```

That 30x40% is not working this way, it becomes pixels 30x40. I can achieve this specific goal in the first example by using resize

```
convert -size 200x100 xc:black \( xc:red -resize 30x40% \) -gravity West -composite out.png
```

In this second version, xc:red inherits the size 200x100, so -resize works as expected. Though the size of further/inner primitives are not reduced to 60x40, it remains 200x100, so in the third example, the green rectangle has orientation landscape and not portrait

```
convert -size 200x150 xc:blue \
  \( xc:red -resize 50x100% \
    \( xc:green -resize 40% \) \
    -gravity Center \
    -composite \
  \) \
  -gravity West \
  -composite \
  out.png
```

So green area is 80x60 pixels, 40% of 200x150. I'd like to somehow reset the size to the size of xc:red after resize by the time I'm introducing xc:green.

Comment: tried +repage, didn't work

Comment: Please say what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: I have a way of thinking like "black square, color right half red, in that half red, put a yellow rectangle in the middle, size of which is the half of of the red rectangle; then put a blue circle to the bottom of that last yellow rectangle"; this is a way of thinking about nested elements. I'm after mapping this way of thinking into ImageMagick primitives. I'm aware that I can, after such chain of thoughts, recompose the image from the inside out though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to create canvases whereby each one is a percentage of the the size of the previous one. There may be an easier way, but you could save each canvas (and implicitly its size) in a MPR *"Magick Persistent Register"* (named lump of RAM) as you create it, then recall the latest one and overwrite it each time you want to do something relative to that:

```
convert -gravity west -size 200x100 xc:black -write MPR:S                      \
   \( MPR:S -resize 30x40% -fill red  -colorize 100 -write MPR:S \) -composite \
   \( MPR:S -resize 50x50% -fill blue -colorize 100 -write MPR:S \) -composite \
   \( MPR:S -resize 50x50% -fill lime -colorize 100 \) -composite  result.png
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could let your `bash`/POSIX shell do it for you inside an *"arithmetic expression"*:

```
W=200
H=100
convert -gravity west -size ${W}x${H} xc:black                    \
   \( -size $((W=W*30/100))x$((H=H*40/100)) xc:red  \) -composite \
   \( -size $((W=W*50/100))x$((H=H*50/100)) xc:blue \) -composite \
   result.png
```

[image]

Be aware that the shell only deals with integer maths, so it's not going to end well if you aim for 50% of 25 pixels...

Comment: Accepted as answer because I was not aware of MPRs and with MPRs, you can cache sizes as images and then "overwrite" them with the desired content.